# jQuery UI blind effect - reveal from bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This could be really obvious and I'm completely missing it.

I've searched for hours and can't seem to find a way to, using jQuery, reveal a hidden div from the bottom up. What I am trying to achieve is exactly as in the following link, but in reverse: http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

I can slide a div from the bottom to the top, but this reveals itself as it moves, rather than being 'masked' in.

Like I said, this could (should?) be really obvious and I'm not seeing it, but I've been looking for ages and can't find a solution to this relatively simple problem.

Thanks,

Ronnie

Comment: @ ronnie can you post a jsfiddle link

Comment: for sure... http://jsfiddle.net/gBY8V/

Comment: the effect i want is as you see here, but reversed (bottom to top)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The effect you're looking for is a little tricky to achieve, but it can be done, even without a wrapper element.

The main issue here is that elements naturally render top-down, not bottom-up. Animating both the `top` and `height` CSS properties of a relatively-positioned element allows us to implement a slide-up effect, but the element will still render top-down:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |  ^
|                                           |  |  Hidden area collapses upwards.
|                                           |  |
+-------------------------------------------+ <-- 'top'
|                                           |  ^
|  |  Upper part of element (visible).      |  |  
|  |                                        |  |  Animation goes bottom-up.
|  |  Element still renders top-down.       |  |  
|  |                                        |  |
+--|----------------------------------------+ <-- 'top + height' 
|  |                                        |  |
|  |  Lower part of element (hidden).       |  |
|  V                                        |  |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

If we want to simulate bottom-up rendering, we have to modify the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) property of the element during the animation, in order for its lower part to always remain in view:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |  ^
|  |  Upper part of element (hidden).       |  |  Hidden area collapses upwards.
|  |                                        |  |
+--|----------------------------------------+ <-- 'top' and 'scrollTop'
|  |                                        |  ^
|  |  Element still renders top-down.       |  |  
|  |                                        |  |  Animation goes bottom-up.
|  |  Lower part of element (visible).      |  |  
|  V                                        |  |
+-------------------------------------------+ <-- 'top + height'
```

We can use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with `scrollTop`, but doing so in conjunction with `top` and `height` did not work correctly in my tests (I suspect `scrollTop` is reset when `top` or `height` are modified in the first animation step, so it ends up stuck to `0`).

To work around this, we can handle `scrollTop` ourselves through the optional [step](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) function we can pass to `animate()`. This function is called with two arguments, `now` and `fx`, `now` being the current value of the animated property and `fx` being a wrapper object around useful information, like the element and property being animated.

Since we always want `scrollTop` to be the same as `top`, we only have to test if `top` is being animated in our `step` function. If it is, we set `scrollTop` to `now`. This solution gives acceptable results, although it flickers a little too much for my taste (that might be an artifact of my browser, though).

So, in summary, to implement that effect, we have to:

- Fetch the element's original height,
- Make the element `position: relative;` so we can animate its `top` property,
- Collapse the element by setting `top` to the original height and `height` to `0`,
- Show the element (necessary in your fiddle since `display: none;` is applied),
- Animate `top` to `0` and `height` to the original height,
- Give `scrollTop` the value of `top` on each animation step.

Resulting in the following code:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    var $revealMe = $("#revealMe");
    var originalHeight = $revealMe.height();
    $revealMe.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: originalHeight,
        height: 0
    }).show().animate({
        top: 0,
        height: originalHeight
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            if (fx.prop == "top") {
                $(fx.elem).scrollTop(now);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBY8V/1/).

Comment: Frederic,
Wow, thankyou for such a detailed, and beautifully crafted response! From what I can see, and from some quick tests, this seems to do work fine. Tricky, yes, but I understand why now. Thankyou :)

Comment: Hi guys, I stumbled upon your solution here, it is really a very detailed response and really helpful. I didn't like the flickering that was going on so I took the liberty to edit your fiddle and I found a solution: [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBY8V/153/)

it is basically the decimal points on scroll top that aren't working well so I found a way to force rounded values. hope it helps!

Comment: @aberonni, thank you for your comment, there is indeed no noticeable flicker :) I would suggest that you post your code in an answer and elaborate how your strategy operates (upvotes will come, no worries about that). Merry `$CHILDREN_RULE_HOLIDAY` :)

Answer (score 6):

How about instead of blind, using slide with a direction option? Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mesWL/)**.

jQuery:

```
$( "#effect" ).show( 'slide', { direction: "down" } , 500);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the slide effect doesn't quite work for me - what I need is for the div to look as if it is being masked (revealed), rather than sliding into view...

Comment: It looks like according to this ticket (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4880) that blinds should have this ability however all I can get it to do is go horizontal or vertical. You could always do this using animate and a wrapper.

Comment: Mmmm, I saw that, and had the same problem as you... How would you achieve this effect using animate and a wrapper?

Comment: No problem, did you want me to update my answer to reflect the last jsFiddle I posted?

Comment: Actually,,, on closer inspection this doesn't actually solve my problem - it will only work where the wrapper div background color matches the site background, but in my case this won't work... Thanks anyway - so close!

Comment: I had problem that blind direction was different in Safari and Firefox with direction option. Using slide solved it too. Thanks, I wish I could +1 twice.

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK to use jQuery UI library you can:

```
$("div").hide("blind", {"direction": "down"});
$("div").show("blind", {"direction": "down"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this do the trick:

```
$("div").show('blind', {}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Not quite - needs to do exactly this, but revealing from the bottom first

Comment: Go for this: $("DIV").show('clip', {direction:'horizontal'}, 'slow');

Comment: Thanks Palantir, this almost works, but still not quite what I'm after.. The clip effect is closer to what I'm after, but I still need the object being revealed to be stationery as it is revealed.

Comment: Maybe, needed to be tested more, b ut you should check animate function of jquery to create a transition between visiblity:hidden and visibility:visible on linear scale to top. Effects of Jquery-ui seems to use display:none as starting parameter, which doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Blind Effect** direction default: `"up"`.

Possible Values: `up`, `down`, `left`, `right`, `vertical`, `horizontal`.

<kbd>**[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/?s=blind)**</kbd>

**Example:**

```js
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "blind", {"direction": "down"}, 1000 );
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```