# jquery animate height upwards

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So I want a div to animate upwards (from botton to top) when a user scrolls down to a certain part of a page.

The problem is I can only get it to animate from top to bottom, I would of thought the opposite would of been easy, apparently not.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 1700) {
        $(".usersuk").animate( 
            { height:"400px" }, 
            { queue: false, duration: 1000 }
        );
    } 
    else {
        $(".usersuk").animate( 
            { height:"0px" }, 
            { queue: false, duration: 1000 }
        );
    }
});
```

Also, is there a better way to animate something when it's visible to the user than using var scroll?

Comment: We will need to see your HTML and CSS too. Usually to achieve this you'll need to make the element's position `fixed` or `absolute`. A http://jsfiddle.net would help.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125040/jquery-ui-blind-effect-reveal-from-bottom

Comment: More or less an example of what @RoryMcCrossan is saying: http://jsfiddle.net/EeVCs/1/ or if the elements height should animate upwards and retain its position: http://jsfiddle.net/EeVCs/

Comment: Yeah I used position absolute and bottom 0% to get it to animate upwards.
How would I change the 'style' of the animation though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to animate from bottom to top, this is quite easy.  All you have to do is set the parent container to position: relative and the animated container to position: absolute with BOTTOM: 0.  It'll stay at the bottom of the parent DIV of course. You can fine tune the animation with some "overflow: hidden" for the object inside the animated container.

Finally, if really want to fire an event on "sight" (element in window), you need to consider scroll position, window height, object position and object height.  This is quite easy, but if you're used to plugin, you can check for the "[inview plugin](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)".  I already used that plugin and it worked perfectly. Hope this helps

Comment: Notice, the "absolute" container won't push on the relative parent, so  can add the absolute div's height to the relative div's height if necessary