# jQuery .slideDown() in opposite direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

We are using `.slideDown()` of jQuery to show a navigation with animation. Unfortunately, it is located at the bottom of the page. So, sliding down from top to bottom looks and feels wrong. It should be the opposite direction.

There is a method called `.slideUp()`, however, it is used to hide the element, not to show it, as it looks.

**Is it possible to "slide down" (=> show element) from bottom to top (instead from top to bottom)?**

[image]

---

### Best Answer

The selected answer from the similar question [jQuery UI blind effect - reveal from bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125040/jquery-ui-blind-effect-reveal-from-bottom) is actually not really satisfying. But there is also an answer further below from [Prof. Desty Nova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863761/prof-desty-nova) which answers this question perfectly in my opinion:

```
$("div").hide("blind", {"direction": "down"});
$("div").show("blind", {"direction": "down"});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mesWL/58/) (updated)

Comment: Can you post your code please with a fiddle?

Comment: This is just a positioning issue, if you position the element at the bottom it will slide up

Comment: Why not use `.animate()`([Ref](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) to adjust the top position of the item you're trying to move?  That said, maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking.