# .slideToggle up from bottom instead of down from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

So I'm trying to display a privacy policy on a single page site. The link is in the footer, and the privacy policy is in a display:none div above it. I'm trying to make the content div slide up from the bottom of the footer, pushing all the content above it up.

**HTML**

```
 <section  id="privContent" class="spotlight">
     <div  class="content">
         <h2>Privacy Policy</h2>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
 </section>

 <section  class="spotlight">
     <div class="content">
         <a target="self" class="privClick">Privacy Policy</a>
     </div>
 </section>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
   $('a[target="self"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
   $('#privContent').slideToggle('2000', "swing");
   });

});
```

I've tried a couple of different things out, and I can't seem to get anything to work. I'm rather inexperienced with jQuery

Comment: You need to use `.animate()` so you can declare exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Related: [jQuery UI blind effect - reveal from bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10125040/464709). Not sure it addresses your exact requirements, but it could be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is similar. Going to look into it and see if I can possibly get something going from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

New snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#privContent').hide();
  $('.privClick').click(function(e) {
    $('#privContent').css('position', 'fixed').css('bottom', '0').slideToggle('2000', "swing").delay(2000).queue(function (next) {
      $(this).slideToggle('2000', "swing");
      next();
    });;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>



<section  id="privContent" class="spotlight">
    <div  class="content">
        <h2>Privacy Policy</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</section>

<section  class="spotlight">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#" target="blank">TDI</a> | <p class="privClick">Privacy Policy</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same slide effect as the question ?

Comment: This does indeed give the same effect as mine. The div is hidden on page load. I'm attempting to reveal it from the bottom up. Also, the link I had was correct. TDI links to something else. I will remove it from the code snippet to prevent further confusion. My mistake.

Comment: @gaemaf This MIGHT work. It does give the effect of rising from the bottom up. The issue I have now is that it covers the footer where the button is to close it, as well as it covers the content above, instead of pushing it up. At least I have the functionality now, though. The rest I should be able to work out. Thank you.